# How do I get string from Arraylist ?

Tags: java, string, sqlite, dictionary, arraylist

I have a `Globals.mylist=new arraylist<hashmap<String,String>>` mylist, and hashmap map1 to keep my product order before I insert them into database. this part was when I insert my product order into Globals.mylist :

```
if (Globals.mylist == null) { 
    Globals.mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
id = bun.getLong("id");
Id=String.valueOf(id);
brand = bun.getString("brand");
type = bun.getString("type");
qty = bun.getString("qty");
if (Globals.mylist.size() == 0) {
  map1.put("one", Id);
  map1.put("two", brand);
  map1.put("three", type);
  map1.put("four", qty); 
  Globals.mylist.add(map1);
} else {
  int j = Globals.mylist.size();
  map1.put("one", Id);
  map1.put("two", brand);
  map1.put("three", type);
  map1.put("four", qty); 
  Globals.mylist.add(j,map1);
}
```

And this part was when I try to get string from Globals.mylist into sqlite

```
for (int i=0; i<Globals.mylist.size();i++) {
map1=Globals.mylist.get(i);
map1.get(Id);
map1.get(qty);
orderdtl = dataSource.createorderdtl(orderid, Id, qty);
}
```

But I get an error. It tells me that `Id=0 and qty=null`. I try to search reference, but I cant implement them. How can I get string id and string qty from `Globals.mylist` to inserted into sqlite.

Comment: Are you using jython?

Comment: `map1.get("one")`, `map1.get("two")`, `map1.get("three")` `map1.get("four")`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i am not using jython

Comment: @WardaLyn Create a class to store your id, brand, type and qty. You almost certainly don't want a `Globals` anything, that's a python idiom and still puzzles me in your code. Why `Globals`?

Comment: Globals.java is my class when i put mylist, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a value from a `Map` you need it's key.

Previously in your code, you generated the map using...

```
map1.put("one", Id);
map1.put("two", brand);
map1.put("three", type);
map1.put("four", qty);
```

Which gives you the keys.  To retreieve the values, you would need to use the appropriate key, for example...

```
map1=Globals.mylist.get(i);
String id = map1.get("one");
String qty = map1.get("four");
```

You might like to take a look through [The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) for more details

Comment: Makes a nice change ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to use LinkedHashMap which is designed to be able to iterate in insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think we have enough code. But the .get(int) function returns an object, it doesn't actually do anything so you'll need to do something like System.out.println(map1.get(Id)).

Comment: `Globals.mylist` is an `ArrayList` of `HashMap` of `String` keys and values, therefore, `Globals.mylist.get(i)` will, if available, return a `HashMap` of `String` keys and values. It's all there in the code - just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to get the `value` of the Map using its `value` which is not the way it is implemented.

```
map1.get(Id);
map1.get(qty);
```

**Not the right way.**

---

You need to call `Map#get` on the `key` whose `value` you need to retrieve. You will get the value of type `String` as you have declared it so retrieve it in the variable of the same type.

```
String Id = map1.get("one");
String qty = map1.get("four");
```

**The right way to call it.**

Answer (score 0):

While adding something to map, you use key value pair.

map.put(key, value);

when you want to get string you should use;

map.get(key);